# jsp page not showing up in browser but tomcat is running in spring suite tool

Tags: tomcat

I'm a HTML designer, we are developing a JSP page site based using spring suite tool.
The browser used to show the site earlier using localhost,but unfortunately my system crashed and I had to re-install everything but now tomcat works fine in spring suite tool but when i enter the address for the site it doesn't show up.
I tried to start the tomcat server manually and in the localhost:8080, tomcat page shows up.

Any solution?

cannot post image as I do not have reputation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if you have any virtual host to which the application is getting mapped. check that port no and try to hit the server.
Check the application if it has got deployed properly in the tomcat.

Comment: I tried checking with the port its default 8080, 
I changed it to 8081 restarted spring tool suite, still nothing but I get the Tomcat page but not the spring index page. I've assigned a domain name in the hosts file to localhost.
when I enter the domain name in address it shows up only the Apache page.

Comment: I meant sometimes application are not mapped to the default host, instead some virtual host. check if such is the case. also check if the application is deployed properly and the path you are giving in the url for the webpage is correct